# Tu B'Shvat Significance

Tags: minhag, history, tu-bishvat

What is the significance of Tu B'Shvat? How was it celebrated through history, and was it celebrated through history? What are the Halachic torah sources for Celebrating it?  Why the recent Popularity?

Answer (score 7):

Tu B'Shvat appears first in Mishnayos Rosh HaShana as one of the four Rosh HaShanas. The first of Shevat is the new year for trees, according to Bais Shamai, however according to Bais Hillel the fifteenth of Shevat. Fruit trees use Tu Bishvat as the cut off date in the Hebrew calendar for calculating the age of a fruit bearing tree. The Halachos of Orlah remain to this very day in the same form it had in talmudic times and uses Tu B'Shvat in the same way.

In the 16th century, the Arizal instituted that on Tu Bishvat we eat fruits from trees of Eretz Yisrael. By the Chassidim, some pickle or candy the Esrog from Sukkos and eat it on Tu Bishvat. Some pray that they will be worthy of a beautiful Esrog on the following Sukkos.

also see this link for more information http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379846/jewish/Tu-BShevat-Basics.htm

Comment: The Arizal lived in the 16th century; not the 17th.  Furthermore I highly doubt that he "instituted" much more likely he merely suggested.  What is the source for the Arizal?

Comment: @mevaqesh - Pri Etz Hadar ספר פרי עץ הדר ווינציה תפ"ח

Comment: Isn't the Tu Bishvat sedder attributed to the chemdas hayamim?

Comment: @user6591: My answer is not regarding the Tu Bishvat Seder, it is regarding eating fruits from Eretz Yisrael.

Answer (score 2):

@mevqesh and @user6591

The “Tu B’Shevat Seder” actually predates the Chemdat HaYamim.

The earliest written mention of the Tu B’Shevat seder comes from a sefer that was first published three years before the Chemdat HaYamim, in 1728 called Birkat Eliyahu by Rabbi Eliyahu of Ulyanov.

Rabbi Eliyahu cites his contemporary, Rabbi Moshe Hagiz of Yerushayalim, regarding a Tu B’Shevat Seder.

There, Rabbi Hagiz clearly states that he himself instituted this custom, based on the words of his Rebbeim: Rabbi Hagiz’ first Rebbe was his father, Rabbi Yakov Hagiz of Morocco zt”l. Following his father’s early death, Rabbi Hagiz studied with his maternal grandfather, Rabbi Moshe “Magen” Galante, zt”l whose own grandfather, Rabbi Moshe Galante of Tzfat  zt”l was a Talmid of the Arizal

This shows a clear chain of tradition from the Arizal down to Rabbi Moshe Hagiz, who first spoke of a "Tu B’Shevat Seder" and formally established it.

Here are the words of Rabbi Hagiz, as quoted by Birkat Eliyahu (page 55):

[image: Birkat Eliyah Page 55- Tu B'Shevat]

…as it is written,” כִּ֤י הָֽאָדָם֙ עֵ֣ץ הַשָּׂדֶ֔ה - man is a tree of the field” [Devarim-Parshat Shoftim 20:19], and so I established a custom, based on what I have seen from my rabbis, and my teacher [Rabbi Moshe Galante] who, on Tu B’Shevat, would customarily recite many blessings on fruits and pray to Hashem to renew for us a good year. And they would eat these fifteen fruits…

Hope this helps.

Chag Sameach!

**.א.ח.י**

Comment: Chemdat Yamim may have first been published in 1731 but it wasn't written in 1731. This is a cool source but you are not representing it correctly. After all Chemdat Yamim also claims to have established it himself, using the same wording כאשר הנהגתי לכל החברים אשר עמדי as I have enacted to all the colleagues who are with me

Comment: What do you mean he "formally established it"? He says he's just doing what his teacher's did. Also, how do you know which teacher he learned it from?

Comment: @Double AA Thank you for your comments and I hope this clarifies the confusion: As you already know the Chemdat Yamim was written anonymously, and although many Gedolim (such as: Rav Yonatan Eybeshutz, Rav Ovadiah Yosef, The Chatam Sofer, The Pri Megadim, The Chaye Adam {The Villna Gaon}, and Rav Alexsander Ziskind,) since its publication in 1732 in Izmir (Ottoman Empire, now Turkey) have referenced it in an extremely very positive holy way. After all it is the source of adding: Ki Gavna, L'Dovid  Ribbono Shel Olam, among other tefilot and minhagim currently done.

Comment: However, there is no definitive time when it was written. and therefore, the masses only knew of its contents after it was published.  Keep in mind that the sefer was also a huge source of controversy for other things written in it and more importantly what was left out of it (Tish B'Av). This along with its anonymity had many Gedolim (such as: Rav Yaakov Emden, The Baal Shem Tov, and many other Chassidic Rebbes) questioned if it was a Shabbetian work, since Shabtai Tzvi y"mz abolished Tish B'Av.

Comment: With that said, there is a widely accepted source that was published in 1728 that relates a timeline that would predate the Chemat Yamin. Rav Eliyahu of Ulyanov cites his contemporary Rabbi Moshe Hagiz who lived from 1671 to 1750 in Tzfat. His first Rebbe, his father Rabbi Yaakov Hagiz of Morroco a fierce anti-Shabbatean who excommunicated Shabbatai Tzvi passed away in 1674 when his son was only 3.

Comment: Rabbi Moshe was then raised and taught by his maternal Grandfather Rabbi Moshe "Magen" Galante who was born in Tzfat and lived from 1621- 1689. Rabbi Moshe Galante was the first Risho L'Tzion of the Chief Rabbinate of Israel. Rabbi Moshe Galante's grandfather, (who was his name sake) Rabbi Moshe Galante of Tzfa,t who died in 1608, was among the talmedei of the Arizal Hakodosh.

Comment: Although there is no direct mention of the Tu B' Shevat Seder in the seforim written about the minagim of the Arizal. This was passed through the generations from Talmid to Talmid as the accepted minhag. Rabbi Yaakov Hagiz is quoted as not just hearing about but seeing his rabbis and specifically his Rebbe (his grandfather) pray to Hashem and say many brochot on 15 specific fruits in that order as well as a brocha and prayer on an esrog.

Comment: The 15 fruits broken into 3 categories represent the 3 spiritual realms of the universe. The first 5 to Beriah- almost no kelipot, and the fruits can be eaten whole. The second 5 to Yetzirah- little kelipot, the fruits can be eaten with the skin but contain an inedible pit. The third 5 to Asisyah- heavy and strong kelipot (this is where we reside) and the fruits have a tough outer shell/peel that needs to be broken before being able to eat the fruit within it.

Comment: The Esrog represents the highest level Atzilut- the purest level no klelipot at all. We dont eat it we smell it, since it was the only sense that was not part of the chet of Adam and Chava and therefore requires no tikun.

Comment: On the side it is why the Ketoret was considered the holiest korban.

Comment: There are of course many other referenced through Tanach and Gemarrah that discuss the importance of smell and the nostrils. Especially the posuk in which Hashem created Adam: 
  בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית - ב':ז'
וַיִּ֩יצֶר֩ יְהֹוָ֨-ה אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶת־הָֽאָדָ֗ם עָפָר֙ מִן־הָ֣אֲדָמָ֔ה וַיִּפַּ֥ח בְּאַפָּ֖יו נִשְׁמַ֣ת חַיִּ֑ים וַֽיְהִ֥י הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְנֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּֽה:"
Hashen Elokim formed man from the dust of the earth. He blew into his nostrils the breath of life, and man became a living being.".

Comment: I hope this helps clear things up and you enjoy the rest of the Chag.   -.א.ח.י

Comment: I'm not really sure how any of that address what I wrote.

Comment: I'm not sure how it doesn't. You seem to know, but won't share when the Chemdat Yamim was written. I was clear in the timeline of the Birkat Eliyahu. Including that the mesora Rabbi Hagiz mentioned came directly from *his Rebbe* who was his Grandfather, who received it from his grandfather, a talmid of the Arizal.

Comment: Let's see. You claimed in the post that it predates the Chemdat Yamim and have provided no proof for that (since you can't since no one knows when Chemdat Yamim was written). You haven't explained how you know which teacher he got it from (or how you know that teacher got it from his grandfather?). You haven't explained what "formally established" means. Thus, I conclude that you haven't addressed anything I wrote.

Comment: I provided proof that the mesora predates the chemdat yomim, I provided proof that we know when the chemday yomim was published. Having a sefer written but not published where others outside of the author and possibly his close contemporaries brings zero legitamacy to establishing a source of a custom. The Birkat Eliyahu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133299/discussion-between--and-double-aa).